# Align event box to the bottom in month view with fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible in fullcalendar to align some event box to the bottom instead of the default normal top align in the month view?
The idea is to have some events aligned up and others aligned down. (Important events up, less important events down (even in the same day)).

Thanx in Advance...
Attorn

Comment: It would really depend on how complex the calendar is. Do you have multiple users? How do you plan on ordering the "important" and/or "non important" events? Are you going to call several event sources? Everything you do would have to be taken into account when creating a relevance algorithm. For something simple, you could probably add a class name into each event object and then use some vertical positioning or float and clear styles to accomplish it. What have you tried?

Comment: It's basic use. I have 2 google eventsources, the first I want to align de boxes to the top, the second source other to the bottom. Only 1 user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would handle it is to make sure that you have your two event sources in the order that you want them to display. AKA. Google 1 then Google 2....
Then I would assign a className: object to the top source and add a css margin-bottom:15px to the className that you gave the source. This will separate the two sources as I think the goal is to do.

Comment: Thnks Juan. I made a test and it works OK. But it would be better looking if all Google2 events aligned to the bottom, and so all of that events would be in the same eight...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that they can actually be aligned to the bottom without changing the fullcalendar.js file which is not recommended. I'll continue to think on it and if I have any more ideas than I'll let you know. Good luck!